# Search - SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, search

I'm trying to write search function, that gets its parameter from the user and uses an SQL statement to get the result from a MySQL database.

The statement:

```
$title = $_GET['title'];    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, phone, email from person where name= '$title'");
```

The problem with this statement is that it's only taking the exact name; if the user is looking for "David" and just types "Da" then no result will be found.

I need a statement that, when the user enters part of the name, displays all matches with "Da".

Comment: Please make your post title describe the question.

Comment: please don't keep your code the way it is.  You must, at a minimum, escape your input, and at best, use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a wildcard search, which is not optimal, but should work:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, phone, email from person where name like '$title%'");
```

Comment: this only checks for wildcards after `$title`

Comment: @Jon: Actually it doesn't even do that.

Comment: @Jon: OP mentioned "if the user looking for "David" and just type "Da" the result will be not found! I need a statement when the user enter part of the name the statement display all matches with "Da" ", so I figured he was only going for wildcard for anything after title, not before.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Missed the quote, Ash corrected (Thanks Ash).

Answer (score 1):

use the `LIKE` condition

```
SELECT name, phone, email
FROM person
WHERE name LIKE '%$title%'
```

This searches for `$title` anywhere in `name`.

Comment: @Reem: For the record, this query will return any matches before AND after the title. So if a search for 'da' is conducted, then rows to be returned would include 'david' and 'tada'.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision - thats what I was going for, but thanks for warning OP.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision Thank you for your attention, the statement edited as you recommended

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO to prevent SQL Injection attacks. [Read it](http://php.net/pdo/), learn it, code it, live it.

You'll want to use the wildcard character - %

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx', $user, $pass );

$sql = "SELECT name, phone, email from person where name LIKE :username";
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->bindValue( ':username', '%' . $_GET['title'] . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR );

$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

print_r( $result );
```

Comment: Won't that escape the wildcards out?

Comment: This is exactly how I'm doing a search function in production code - by binding the wildcard as part of the value.

Comment: @TimG: This is exactly how I had it as well, the wildcard is to be concatenated to the title, not part of the title, but I was promptly corrected. If it works in your scenario, this should be the way to go imo. However the OP did state he is using mysql procedural calls so chances of him switching to PDO are limited.

Comment: It's worth trying to convince people to switch - it's that important.  SQL Injection is a HUGE problem and ignoring it just makes it worse.  Your query, as you posted it had the wildcard outside the tick marks - that is incorrect.  With parameterized queries there are no tick marks to worry about - it's a bound parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read this, it will be useful to you:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: w3schools linkes are frowned upon on SO. The technical validity is usually [low](http://w3fools.com/), and it's googlespammed already.